# How to add plugins to .m2 repository (for those not found by pom.xml)

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to import via a pom.xml file the following plugin:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
```

I looked inside the .m2 repository and this plugin wasn't present. I downloaded the jar and added it in the plugin folder inside the .m2 folder, but the pom.xml file still doesn't recognize (not found) this plugin.

Is there something I can try to make the pom.xml import this plugin in the project? This question applies for a couple of dependencies and plugins and can't seem to successfully import from the pom.xml files I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Maven will download the dependencies automatically and fill in the .m2 directory, you do not need to download them manually.

Comment: This is kind of why I wrote this question. It doesn't seem to have done it in this case, since the plugin is not found by the pom.xml file.

Comment: Therefore, how did you try to launch maven (command line, arguments, ...) and what was the output? You need to describe more precisely what you tried to do and what was the output, to help people answer your question in your specific context.

Comment: You also need to update the metadata. Much easier to run an install target.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my question, this is work related and I tried to mvn clean install with the tool bar and via the terminal, I tried with the -U option, I tried the suggestion from s.ufer, and I tried to add manually the package to the .m2 repository. It is still not found by maven.

Answer (score 1):

Maven will download everything you specify in your POM from a repository on the internet (https://search.maven.org/) for you. As Alexandre mentioned.

There are a number of reasons why it might not work:

1. You don't have a connection to the internet or you are behind a proxy.This happens mostly in companies.
2. The dependency or plugin you want doesn't exist or you have a typo. I don't see that with you.
   https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/properties-maven-plugin/1.1.0/maven-plugin
3. Your IDE doesn't automatically triggers Maven to start the download after you have added something to the POM and saved the POM.

You might try to manually download the plugin via Maven:

1. Open a terminal inside the directory of the POM.
2. Try the following command:

   ```
   mvn -U dependency:sources dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
   ```
3. Does it work or do you get any errors?

PS: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment...so I misuse the answer.